# Complex Analytic Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The following question appears in Rosenlicht's *Introduction to Analysis*, which is primarily a real analysis text, but contains some problems about complex analysis:
[image]

I believe I've managed to prove parts (a) and (b) by showing $|f(z)| > \frac{1}{2}|z|^n$ when $|z|$ is large enough. From there, you can show you can find a disk centered around the origin that contains the point $z \in \mathbb{R}$ corresponding to the minimum.

I'm stuck on parts (c) and (d). I don't understand the algebraic manipulations that allow one to express $f(z)$ in the manner shown in (c). Does it depend on the remainder theorem? I also don't quite follow the argument of part (d), particularly the inequality shown in that part.

Thanks.

Comment: In (d) we have  $f(\zeta+\alpha t) =f(\zeta)(1-t^m-t^{m+1}\alpha \cdot g(z)). $ Now $\alpha$ is  fixed and  $g(z)$ is bounded on any bounded region. So if $t>0$ and $t$ is small enough we have     $ |t^{m+1} \alpha \cdot  g(z)|<t^m,$ implying $|1-t^m-t^{m+1}\alpha \cdot g(z)|<1.$

Comment: This theorem (first proved by Gauss) is actually  a special case  of the following: If $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is analytic (That is, the complex derivative $f'(z)$ exists for all $z$) then the real-valued function $h(z)=|f(z)|$ cannot have a local extremal value other than $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question $c)$, remember that for polynomials, Taylors's formula is an exact formula, i.e. if the polynomial $f$ has degree $n$, 
$$f(z)=f(\zeta)+f'(\zeta)(z-\zeta)+\dots+\frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!}(z-\zeta)^n. $$
Some $f^{(i)}(\zeta)$ maybe $0$, depending on the multiplicity of $\zeta$ as a root of $f(z)-f(\zeta)=0$. If $m$ is the first order of derivation such that $f^{(m)}(\zeta)\ne 0$, Taylor's formula is
\begin{align}
f(z)&=f(\zeta)+\frac{f^{(m)}(\zeta)}{m!}(z-\zeta)^m+\dots+\frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!}(z-\zeta)^n\\
&=f(\zeta)+\frac{f^{(m)}(\zeta)}{m!}(z-\zeta)^m\biggl(1+\dots+\frac{m!\,f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!\,f^{(m)}(\zeta)}(z-\zeta)^{n-m}\biggr).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not sure of how to apply Taylor's formula to get to the form shown in (c).

Comment: @ZainSiddiqui: I've added some details.

Comment: Just a note that we must have some $m \in \Bbb{Z}_+$ with $f^{(m)}(\zeta) \ne 0$, as $n \in \Bbb{Z}_+$ and $f^{(n)}(\zeta)= n!a_0 \ne 0$ where $a_0$ is coefficient of $z^n$ the highest order term in the polynomial. (I think $a_0 = 1$ here.)

Comment: Yes, there's at least the value $m=n$ which answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here that Bernard's answer is sufficient for part c), I shall go through part d). [Let me know if further guidance is needed for part c)]

We know that we can write $$f(z) = f(\zeta) a(z-\zeta)^m(1+(z-\zeta)g(z))$$
Where $m \in \Bbb{Z}_+, a \in \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $g(z)$ is a polynomial in $z$.

Now following the hint we can choose $\alpha \in \Bbb{C}$ with $\alpha^m = -\frac{f(\zeta)}{a}$ as $a \ne 0$.

writing $z=\zeta + t\alpha$ and plugging into the formula for $f(z)$ that 3) gives us gives:
$$f(\zeta + t\alpha) = f(\zeta) + a(t\alpha)^m(1+(t\alpha)g(\zeta + t\alpha))$$
Which becomes, using $\alpha^m = -\frac{f(\zeta)}{a}$:
$$f(\zeta + t\alpha) = f(\zeta)(1-t^m+t^{m+1}\alpha g(\zeta + t\alpha))=f(\zeta)(1+t^m(t\alpha g(\zeta + t\alpha)-1))$$
However we now let $t$ tend to $0$, and note that as $g(z)$ is a polynomial;
$\lim \limits_{t \to 0} \ g(\zeta + t\alpha)=g(\zeta)$ by continuity of polynomials, which is a finite value; so:
$\lim \limits_{t \to 0} \ [t\alpha g(\zeta + t\alpha)]=0$

Hence we can make $-1<t^m(t\alpha g(\zeta + t\alpha ) -1)<0$ and so;
$|f(\zeta + t\alpha)| =|f(\zeta)||(1 + t^m(t\alpha g(\zeta + t\alpha)-1))|<|f(\zeta)|$ as long as $f(\zeta) \ne 0$

Which is the contradiction that was required.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then would that mean $f(\zeta+t\alpha)=0$ for all $t$?

Comment: Yes that’s true... well, kind of. In the case $f(\zeta)=0$ which you are using, we see $\alpha = 0$ and so $\forall t, f(\zeta +t\alpha)=f(\zeta)=0$

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I have a decent grasp on what's going on now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove (c) this way: Let $p(z)= c_0 + c_1z + \cdots +c_nz^n$ be a polynomial of degree $n\ge 1.$ Let $a\in \mathbb C.$ Then there exist constants $d_1,\dots, d_n,$ $d_n\ne 0,$ such that

$$\tag 1 p(z) = p(a) + d_1(z-a) + d_2(z-a)^2 +\cdots + d_n(z-a)^n$$

for all $z\in \mathbb C.$ Conclusion (c) follows readily from this.

Proving $(1)$ is simple when $n=1.$ Suppose it holds for $n\ge 1.$ Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n+1.$ Then $p(z) - p(a)$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$ that vanishes at $a.$ Hence $(z-a)$ divides $p(z) - p(a),$ i.e., $p(z)-p(a) = (z-a)q(z)$ for some polynomial $q$ of degree $n.$ Because $(1)$ holds for $n,$ $q(z) = q(a) + d_1(z-a) + \cdots + d_n(z-a)^n.$ Thus

$$p(z) - p(a) = (z-a)(q(a) + d_1(z-a) + \cdots + d_n(z-a)^n)$$ $$= q(a)(z-a) + d_1(z-a)^2 + \cdots + d_n(z-a)^{n+1}.$$

This proves $(1).$